# How to make a scene wipe transition in Unity?

Tags: unity-game-engine, scene

Please [see this Wikipedia animation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:A2o_wipes.ogv) for what I mean by a wipe transition.

How would I implement a similar effect for transitions between Unity scenes? I have scene A and scene B and when transitioning from A to B both have to be shown on the screen until the transition finishes. All Unity examples I have been able to find of transitions typically have scene A go to pure black then from black to scene B.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! This community is not for asking "Please someone implement XY for me" but rather about "Please someone help me with this specific issue I encountered while implementing this specific code I added to my question where I try to achieve XY but instead ZZ happens". Please make sure to take the  [Tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and also refer to [What topics can I ask about here?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 0):

You can only have one scene loaded at time like in [this](http://www.alanzucconi.com/2016/03/23/scene-management-unity-5/) document

"Ghost scenes. Every time you load a new level with SceneManager.LoadScene, Unity flushes all the scenes that have been previously loaded. Only game objects that invoked DontDestroyOnLoad (documentation) survive the process."

What you can do is to open more scenes with the [Multi-scene editing](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/MultiSceneEditing.html) and try to animate object with a fade-in or fade-out animation that have a `DontDestroyOnLoad()` on them.